# sympy:Please tell me about the line.equation()

Tags: sympy

sympy.line.equation()

Same value and type, but what's the difference?"

How can I fix it?

What is the difference between z1 and z2?

```
from sympy import *
var('x y z1 z2')
z1=8*x+6*y+48
print("#z1",z1,type(z1))

z2=Line(Point(-6,0),Point(0,-8)).equation()
print("#z2",z2,type(z2))

if type(z1)==type(z2):
    print("#","type==")
else:
    print("#","type<>")
if z1==z2:
    print("#","==")
else:
    print("#","<>")
#z1 8*x + 6*y + 48 <class 'sympy.core.add.Add'>
#z2 8*x + 6*y + 48 <class 'sympy.core.add.Add'>
# type==
# <>
```

I try add .expand().simplify()    30 mins ago

```
from sympy import *
var('x y')
print("#z1#",solve(8*x+6*y+ 48                                                 ,y))
print("#   ",      Line(Point(-6,0),Point(0,-8)).equation().expand().simplify()   )
print("#z2#",solve(Line(Point(-6,0),Point(0,-8)).equation().expand().simplify(),y))
#z1# [-4*x/3 - 8]
#    8*x + 6*y + 48
#z2# []
```

Thank you.

```
from sympy import *
var('x y')
print("#z1#",solve(8*x+6*y+ 48                                           ,y))
print("#   ",                  Line(Point(-6,0),Point(0,-8)).equation()     )
print("#z2#",solve(sympify(str(Line(Point(-6,0),Point(0,-8)).equation())),y))
#z1# [-4*x/3 - 8]
#    8*x + 6*y + 48
#z2# [-4*x/3 - 8]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you don't tell `equation` what symbols to use, it creates its own symbols `x` and `y` with assumptions appropriate for a line (i.e. real). When you create a symbol with `var` the symbols are created with only commutative assumptions. Symbols that have different assumptions do not compare equal.

```py
>>> from sympy import Line, oo
>>> Line((0,0),slope=oo).equation()
x
>>> _._assumptions
{'real': True, 'commutative': True, 'infinite': False, 'extended_real': True,
 'hermitian': True, 'complex': True, 'imaginary': False, 'finite': True}
>>> var('x')
x
>>> _._assumptions
{'commutative': True, 'zero': None}
>>> Line((0,0),slope=oo).equation(x)  # supply value of x to use
x
>>> _ == x
True
>>> Line((0,0),slope=oo).equation() == x  # no default given
False
```

So...if you want to compare expression built by Line and yourself, use the same symbols (i.e. provide the defaults to `Line.equation`. Otherwise the hidden assumptions will cause issues.

```py
>>> from sympy.abc import y
>>> Line(Point(-6,0),Point(0,-8)).equation(x,y)
8*x + 6*y + 48
>>> _==8*x + 6*y + 48
True
```

Answer (score 1):

The equality operator (==) in SymPy tests whether expressions **have identical form, not whether they are mathematically equivalent**.

If you want to determine the *mathematical equivalence* of nontrivial expressions, you should apply a more advanced simplification routine to both sides of the equation. In the case of polynomials, expressions can be rewritten in a canonical form by expanding them fully. This is done using the *.expand()* method in SymPy - in your case:

```
print(bool(z1.expand()==z2.expand()))
```

or

```
print((z1-z2).expand())
```

In first case *True* will be resulted for equivalent expressions. In second case  you will get 0 (zero) if expressions are equivalent. But you will have  *False* and *8*x - 8*x - 6*y + 6*y* instead.

If you try *simplify()*, which attempt more advanced transformations, you will get the same result:

```
print(simplify(z1-z2))
```

That means that your expressions has same type and 'value', but **not mathematically equivalent**. See detail [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Faq#why-does-sympy-say-that-two-equal-expressions-are-unequal).

Comment: The equations are in identical form but they are using symbols with different assumptions, in this case.